# Can unexposed PMMA be reused (successfully exposed) after development?

Tags: experimental-physics, nanoscience

Can unexposed PMMA be reused (successfully exposed) after development?

To clarify, [PMMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly%28methyl_methacrylate%29) is exposed using an electron beam in an SEM, and then the exposed areas are removed using a developer solution, because the exposed regions are de-crosslinked and thus dissolve in the developer, while the unexposed regions are not.

My question is, could you reuse a sample in the areas that weren't exposed the first time, if you have developed it? Is there any reason the developer would modify the unexposed PMMA?

My intuition says that you should be able to reuse it, but I don't know and can't find any answers online.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know Plexiglas could be used for that. I suspect you're right, assuming the developer doesn't diffuse into the unexposed plastic. What is the developing chemical?

Comment: PMMA is actually possibly the most widely used e-beam resist! The most common developer is an MIBK/IPA solution.

Comment: Cool. If you have access to it, it seems like it'd be worth a try to verify your guess if you can't find any info about it online.